# RAII sockets: when to release (close)

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, raii

I want to write a simple, small C++ RAII wrapper over a C socket.

The question is in what state is a socket considered initialized (from the perspective of RAII) and so eligible for release.

For instance, for a TCP client socket: if the `socket` call succeed, but the `connect` call failed, should `close` be called?

This is just an example, I am interested in a general answer, something like:

- Each socket successfully created by `socket` must be closed.
  or
- There must be a close for each `connect`, `listen` or `accept`.

The man pages for `socket` & friends and `close` are not very clear (or at least to me).

Comment: If you have a valid/active socket handle then it's been initialized.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious When is a socket handle considered vaid/active?

Comment: The socket handle is valid when `socket` or `accept` return a value other than `INVALID_SOCKET` and until you `close` the handle.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious ty, I think this constitutes an answer.

Comment: `INVALID_SOCKET` is a WinSock constant, @CaptainObvlious. In Unix tradition, Linux uses filedescriptors that are just indices into a zero-based array, so anything that is less than zero is a "faulty" return value from e.g. `socket()`. Oh, and checking for negative values fails for WinSock on 64 bits, because there the socket handle type is an unsigned integer, if I remember correctly (it's been a while, I must admit).

Comment: One way to go is to make a very simple wrapper, that only calls close on desctruction of the wrapper object. It can also provide a manual close() for explicitly closing. This gives you a lot of control with little code, and you make sure you do not leak socket descriptors on exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

The two parts to pair up for sockets are `socket()` with `close()` and `connect()` with `shutdown()`. As you see, it doesn't get as easy as with `malloc()` and `free()`. This is further complicated by the fact that not every socket is used to `connect()`, some also use `bind()` and `accept()` instead. However, if you call `close()` without `shutdown()`, it's just a forceful shutdown that is experienced as an error by the remote side, but you correctly release resources that were allocated.

I'd consider wrapping it twice, once to invoke `close()` and another time to invoke `shutdown()`. I wouldn't worry too much about the second part though, as failure to `shutdown()` is still mostly harmless.

Comment: @bolov: As Ulrich says, you do not need to worry too much about calling `shutdown` as failing to do so will not leak resources. So I would not bother wrapping it with RAII. The rule on Unix is pretty simple: If any call returns a file descriptor >= 0 (`open`, `socket`, `accept`, `dup`...), you must `close` it to avoid a resource leak.